# Rewrite rules conflict for .htaccess in two Virtual Hosts (front end + API) in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: .htaccess, vuejs2, apache2, laravel-9, ubuntu-22.04

I'm testing a new website that runs the front end in Vue2 and the backend API in Laravel 9, each on their own separate Virtual Hosts in Ununtu 22.04. As this is a new version of my current website in production, for testing purposes I need to run it in a subdomain "vue.mydomain.com". The API routes are accessed from the url "api.mydomain.com/api".

The problem is that I'm not familiar with .htaccess rewrite rules and when the API routes are called, they are being redirected from "api.mydomain.com" to "vue.mydomain.com".

This is the .htaccess code in the Vue virtual host:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]

# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.html [NC,L]

# Disable directory browsing 
Options -Indexes
```

How should I set the above rules to exclude the "api." subdomain?

Bellow is the .htaccess in the API virtual host. It's in /public folder as the API hosts user uploaded image files. The files are accessed by the url "api.mydomain.com/uploads/user_id/image.jpg" but I wrote a rewrite rule to convert the subdomain to "vue.".

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.mydomain\.com  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://vue.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The API url routes works fine if I remove the htaccess from the Vue virtual host.

Bellow is how each virtual host is set on Apache2 .conf files on /sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.api.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api.mydomain.com/public_html/mydomain-api/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/api.mydomain.com/public_html/mydomain-api/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vue.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.vue.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vue.mydomain.com/mydomain-vue
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/vue.mydomain.com/mydomain-vue>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to limit your redirect from `api.` to `vue.` to specific paths only; to anything below `/uploads/`? Try and add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/` to that redirect.

Comment: Where should I put it exactly in API .htaccess?

Comment: To the block that redirects from the api to the vue subdomain.